# Which one is best approach class or structs? In c++

Tags: c++

Suppose you have to develop an application for XYZ bank with the following features.
1)The application must be secure
2)For transactions, proper interfaces will be provided to the customers.
3)The application must be reusable.
4)The application must be efficient in terms of speed and memory  usage.
You can use either structs or class in order to achieve the above mentioned features. So which programming construct (class or struct) will you select for application development. 
Please help me out here. Thanks

Comment: Makes absolutely no difference, except the public vs private default.

Comment: Which will be more efficient for such type of scenario? And why?

Comment: Notice that StackOverflow is not a *do-my-homework* site

Comment: some people might have a vague convention of using structs for POD types and classes for everything else but its not set in stone

Comment: c++ does not have structs and classes. c++ has only classes that can be declared with the keywords `struct` / `class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`struct` and `class`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes) are nearly equivalent in C++ (you can have member functions, constructors & destructors, data members in both). More precisely,

```
struct Sometype {
 /// some code here
};
```

is *equivalent* to

```
class Sometype {
public:
 /// some code here
};
```

So the runtime efficiency is the same (since `public:` is an annotation for the compiler which is lost, as most type information, at runtime; be aware of [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure)).

You really should take days to read some [good book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) about C++ programming, then look into some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site, then read (or at least refer to) some C++ standard like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (for C++11; for later standards, find them by yourself).

Learn about the [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) and about standard [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).